# Xamarin DisplayAlert not work on android live player

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-live-player

I use DisplayAlert in my project for displaying content of page, it works on UWP(universal Windows) local machine. But when i try to use this application on Xamarin live player on Android my button does not want work.
my code in button_Clicked:

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
Page p = new Page();
byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(URL);
var download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);                 
p.DisplayAlert("page:", download, "close");
```

Difrent button without DisplayAlert works well in Live player.

Answer (score 0):

The live player has many [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/limitations). It's better to test your app on an emulator or test it on a real device through a USB-cable.

And I think you should just call `this.DisplayAlert("page:", download, "close")` instead of `p.DisplayAlert("page:", download, "close");`